# Set doesn't work in for + if in bat script, even if set ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Tags: batch-file

My Script (a.bat):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if "%1"=="on" (
    FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface ^| findstr Local') DO (set lanst=%%a)
    set lanst=%lanst: =%
    echo Local Area Connection: %lanst%

    FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%b in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr SSID ^| findstr /v B') DO (set curwifi=%%b)
    set curwifi=%curwifi: =%
    echo Current Wifi: %curwifi%
)
```

When I run this script in commandline, seems the set dosen't work in for + if:
[image: if+for]

---

But when I remove if-statement, the script is:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo %1

    FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface ^| findstr Local') DO (set lanst=%%a)
    set lanst=%lanst: =%
    echo Local Area Connection: %lanst%

    FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%b in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr SSID ^| findstr /v B') DO (set curwifi=%%b)
    set curwifi=%curwifi: =%
    echo Current Wifi: %curwifi%
```

the result shows:
[image: only-for]

According the output, I found, in the situation of if+for, seems the statement in do() will not be executed.
Why's that, and how to fix?

Comment: Delayed expansion is needed in case a variable is modified and read in a parenthesised block of code; the `if` statement constituts such a block, so you need to use `!lanst!` rather than `%lanst%`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if "%1"=="on" (
    FOR /F "tokens=1" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface ^| findstr Local') DO (
        set lanst=%%a
    )
    set lanst=!lanst: =!
    echo Local Area Connection: !lanst!

    FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%b in ('netsh wlan show interface ^| findstr SSID ^| findstr /v B') DO (
        set curwifi=%%b
    )
    set curwifi=!curwifi: =!
    echo Current Wifi: !curwifi!
)
```

here's more info about the [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: To highlight the quite subtle difference here, when using ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION you use '!' instead of '%' to obtain the delayed-expansion value of the variable.